# LINQ where in List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i have list of projects iD

IEnumerable projects

That contains four numbers ,let's say 2,5,6,9

and this is my AllProjects

```
 IEnumerable<Project> AllProjects = await ctx.Projects.Where(x => x.ClientID == clientid).Where(y => y.Released == true).ToListAsync();
```

i want to filter my AllProjects with project id 2,5,6,9

should be some thing like ...

```
 AllProjects = AllProjects.Where(x=>x.ProjectID == ????)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
AllProjects = AllProjects.Where(x=>projects.Contains(x.ProjectID))
```

You just need to check if the projects list contains the id you are looking for